# how to show different pages to different types of users in flutter

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I want to show 3 types of pages according to user types - 'MyPage' to customers type, 'MyPagePro' to professionals type, and 'Choice' to new users type when they open the app. However, my following code shows an error at the part 'snapshot.document'. I don't know what should be corrected. Please help.

```
 class Wrapper extends StatelessWidget {
 @override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
final user = Provider.of<User>(context);
Future snapshot = Firestore.instance
    .collection('crews')
    .document(user.uid)
    .collection('pros')
    .getDocuments();

if (user == null) {
  return Choice();
} else if (snapshot.documents.length == 0) {
  return MyPage();
} else {
  return MyPagePro();
  }
 }
}
```

I used Future Builder as 'lenz' suggested, and my problem was solved although there is a red screen showing for a few seconds before going to the pages I intended. Thanks, lenz!

```
class Wrapper extends StatelessWidget {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
final user = Provider.of<User>(context);
final uid = user.uid;
return FutureBuilder(
    future: Firestore.instance
        .collection('crews')
        .document(user.uid)
        .collection('pros')
        .getDocuments(),
    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<dynamic> snapshot) {
      if (user == null) {
        return Choice();
      } else if (snapshot.documents.length == 0) {
        return MyPage();
      } else {
        return MyPagePro();
      }
    });
```

Comment: Still you’re not writing what the problem with the current code is. Previous question was closed probably because you don’t take the time to write a good question but you expect someone to take the time to write a good answer.

Comment: I edited my question. I forgot to write a question, now I added it.

Comment: Is my answer helpful? If it’s not let me know

Comment: It’s good practice to post the error code and avoid the format “I'm getting an error there”. The full error message has specific information that is useful to help you (and others) debug (filename, line number, potential fixes...). Add the full error message to help us debug with you.

Comment: I posted a new code, which still have an error.

Comment: Show the full error message. Read my previous comment.

Comment: And you deleted if (snapshot.hasData), if (snapshot.hasError), and the else scenario...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you are using a Future synchronously. The Future needs to get the data from the server before you can use it. This does not happen instantly.

One solution is to use a [FutureBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html). This give you access to the Future’s response synchronously. First your Future will be without data (the else scenario below). Then when the server responds, it will be either have data or have an error.

Try something like this:

```
class Wrapper extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<CollectionReference>(
    future: Firestore.instance.collection('pros').getDocuments(),
    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<CollectionReference> snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.hasData) {
        // return either the MyPage or Authenticate widget
        if (user == null) {
          return Choice();
        } else if (snapshot.documents.length == 0) {
          return MyPage();
        } else {
          return MyPagePro();
        }
      } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
        //TODO if Future resolves with error case
      } else {
        //TODO While Future is loading case
        // e.g.:
        return Text('Awaiting result...'),
      }
    },
  )
}
```

Comment: Note that Im not 100% sure if CollectionReference  is the right data type. If not just replace it with the right return type. The one returned by Firestore.instance.collection('pros').getDocuments(). Sorry Im not on a computer to confirm this right now.

Comment: ....to get that info, you can just hover your mouse over .getDocument() method in VSCode or AndroidStudio. You can also remove <CollectionReference> altogether. It will give you less Intellisense though

Comment: If my answer is useful, please take a second to upvote it and accept it

Comment: I followed your advice, but have more errors with your code. Thanks for your time, but it wasn't a solution

Comment: It is for sure a solution to the issue that you posted. If you are getting different errors post them too

Comment: I copied and pasted your code and had multiple errors especially in builder part. When I did whatever to remove the errors, I have an error at the exactly same part as before -'snapshot.documents' .

Comment: Can you tell me what version of cloud_firestore you’re using?

Comment: I use firebase_auth 0.15.3, and cloud_firestore: 0.13.0+1

Comment: And what error are you getting exactly. Please post the full error in your question.

Comment: This is the correct answer my friend, if you’re having more issues you should post the specific error message if you want help, or read up on [futures and async programming](https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await). Your code shows that you have don’t understand async programming, which will hurt you in the long run

Comment: I think your code was right, but it takes so much time to get documents that app shows red screen for a while before finally starts the first page. Do you have any better idea to show different pages according to user's types? Do I have to use shared preferences?

Comment: Thanks for your help, lenz.